# Who manages the XeTeX examples

Tags: online

Who is the contact about the XeTeX examples over at http://www.tug.org/mactex/src/Demos/XeTeX-showcase?

I'd like to submit a new example, but there's no contact name.

Comment: send a mail to office@tug.org and ask for an email

Comment: For an email? To get an email address?

Comment: yes, the office will tell you who maintains this web page

Comment: Ah right, I thought you mean I had to ask to get an email @tug.org :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.macosx/26095 mailinglist post:

> the XeTeX showcase is not part of any TeX distribution per se. It is included instead in the Demos section of the MacTeXtras additional install available from  (see the MaxTeXtras section near the bottom of the page), and is identical to the online showcase at http://www.tug.org/mactex/src/Demos/XeTeX-showcase/.

So, I guess you need a developer of MacTeX: http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/support/emailform/

**Update**
The showcase is also mentioned at the package description of MacTeXtras: http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/mactextras.html